# Grafico de dispersión con ejes horarios - matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

Estoy intentando dibujar un grafico de dispersion que relaciona las horas en que sucede cada evento con la duracion de estos, pero me esta sucediendo que pyplot me imprime en el eje x la fecha completa (año/mes/dia + hh/mm/ss).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es tener en el eje x solo las horas con un espaciado uniforme para que no se solapen.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

x =["12:45","12:54","15:56","16:15","17:59","18:08","19:32","20:00","21:12","23:47","15:08","13:14","14:34","09:06","08:56"]
duracion = [6,1,5,8,3,23,12,28,18,10,2,4,6,8,8]
xFormato = []

condicion = "18:00"
condicionFormato = datetime.datetime.strptime(condicion, "%H:%M")
for i in x:
    xFormato.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%H:%M'))

contMayores = 0
contMenores = 0
for i  in xFormato:
    if i.time() > condicionFormato.time():
        contMayores = contMayores + 1
    else:
        contMenores = contMenores + 1

plt.scatter(xFormato, duracion)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, debes especificar una formato para el eje <kbd>X</kbd>, de forma que solo se muestre el tiempo (`H:M`) y no la fecha. Esto lo puedes usando  `matplotlib.dates.mdates` para especificar el formato y luego asignarlo al eje mediante `axis.set_major_formatter`

Por otro lado debes ajustar los limites del eje <kbd>X</kbd> del gráfico

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime


x = [
    "12:45", "12:54", "15:56", "16:15", "17:59", "18:08", "19:32",
    "20:00", "21:12", "23:47", "15:08", "13:14", "14:34", "09:06", "08:56"
    ]

duracion = [6, 1, 5, 8, 3, 23, 12, 28, 18, 10, 2, 4, 6, 8, 8]
dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(h, "%H:%M") for h in x]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.scatter(dates, duracion)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
xformater = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xformater)
ax.set_xlim(
    (
     min(dates) - datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
     max(dates) + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
     )
)


plt.show()
```

---

Otra posibilidad es no usar `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` y hacer uso de `matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime


x = [
    "12:45", "12:54", "15:56", "16:15", "17:59", "18:08", "19:32",
    "20:00", "21:12", "23:47", "15:08", "13:14", "14:34", "09:06", "08:56"
    ]

duracion = [6, 1, 5, 8, 3, 23, 12, 28, 18, 10, 2, 4, 6, 8, 8]
dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(h, "%H:%M") for h in x]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot_date(dates, duracion)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
xformater = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xformater)
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]